# Spring, Thymeleaf redirect to the wrong controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

The problem is when i click on button (at homeHeader.html) which should redirect me to JobOfferController.java and then to > viewJobslist(), but it didn't happened because it redirect me to login page.

**JobOfferController.java**

```
@Controller
public class JobOfferController {

@Autowired
private JobOfferService jobOfferService;

@RequestMapping(path ="/jobsList" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewJobsList(Model model){
        List<JobOffer> jobOfferList = jobOfferService.lisAll();
        model.addAttribute("jobOfferList", jobOfferList);
        return "viewJobs.html";
    }
}
```

viewJobs.html

```
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/homeHeader.html :: header"></div>
<div align="center">
<h1>Lista ogłoszeń</h1>
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tytul</th>
            <th>Lokalizacja</th>
            <th>Opis</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="jobOffer : ${jobOfferList}">
            <td th:text="${jobOffer.title}">Tytul</td>
            <td th:text="${jobOffer.location}">Lokalizacja</td>
            <td th:text="${jobOffer.description}">Opis</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

fragment of **homeHeader.html** using Bootstrap classes

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="/jobsList">Job list</a>
</li>
```

**LoginController.java**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("login.html");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

I also use **ResourceHandlerRegistry**

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**", "/static/**", "/templates/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/webjars/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/templates/");
}
```

I think that in JobOfferController.java is everything ok, but the problem could be with SpringSecurit which not allow me to redirect to JobOfferController.

Fragment of **SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/all/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
            .antMatchers("/employee/**").hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .successHandler(sucessHandler)
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", 
"/img/**","/webjars/**","/templates/**", "/font/**");
}
```

[There is fragment structure of project which maybe help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsgiT.png)

Comment: your (security & rest) configuration(as posted) is consistent with your (problem) description: `/jobsList` (path context) matches (only) `.anyRequest().authenticated()` (in you security config), thus is redirected to login page (`/login`) ...if you want to "open" that page: try `@RequestMapping(path ="/all/jobsList" ,...` (because `.antMatchers("/all/**").permitAll()`) or just: `.antMatchers("/jobsList").permitAll()`

Comment: Adding to xerx59's comment, you can use RequestMapping at controller class level to prefix all your URI's with "/all" so every RequestMapping into JobOfferController will be always "/all/**" where ** would be the name put into RequestMapping

Comment: Thank you very much you helped a lot

Comment: You can also simply return `"viewJobs"`.  And use `@GetMapping` since it's a little shorter.